# Using Checkbox and Filterable in RecycleView Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm creating a project, that uses a webservice to fetch the number of departments and there names and creates dynamic checkboxs.
Then I'm using filterable to filter the adapter , by checking from sharedpreferences if the checkbox is checked if not checked I try to hide it from the adapter
(TicketsActivity):

```
for (int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++) {
    if (!getFromSP(filterList.get(i) + i)) {
       mAdapter.getFilter("Department").filter(filterList.get(i).toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

and afther that

```
if (recyclerView.getAdapter() == null) {
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0,ticketList.size()-1);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else {
   recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(0,ticketList.size()-1);
}
```

And in my custom Adapter
(TicketsAdapter):

```
public Filter getFilter(final String type) {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                ticketListFiltered = ticketList;
            } else if (type.equals("Search")) {
                List<Ticket> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Ticket row : ticketList) {
                    if (row.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence) || row.getDate().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence) || row.getPriority().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence)) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }
                ticketListFiltered = filteredList;
            } else {
                List<Ticket> filteredList;
                filteredList = ticketList;
                for (Ticket row : ticketList) {
                    if (row.getDepartment().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence)) {
                        filteredList.remove(row);
                    }
                }
                ticketListFiltered = filteredList;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values =ticketListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return  ticketListFiltered == null ? 0 : ticketListFiltered.size();
}
```

However this throws an Exception on 'int java.util.List.size()' getItemCount, if i change the   filteredList.remove(row) to filteredList.add(row) it will work find,but i need to remove from the adapter rows with "unchecked" department.But for some reason instead of filtering the adapter, its actualy deleting rows direcly of the adapter. I can't find what i'm doing wrong.
Btw this works fine with SearchView

Comment: What exception does it throws?

Comment: @Tenten Ponce java.lang.NullPointerException:

Comment: Did you try checking if null, return 0, otherwise, return ticketListFiltered.size()

Comment: @Tenten Ponce Yeah that kind of works, but checking/unchecking the checkboxes makes unpredictable effects on the adapter

Comment: @Tenten Ponce for some reason instead of filtering the adapter, its actualy deleting rows direcly of the adapter..

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried Filter on recyclerView, I'm just using SearchView. I only try to solve your exception by handling it properly.